# Excluding a tuples_in list in prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

This is the problem in short:
16 children are to be seated in a 4 x 4 array of chairs. The children are 8 girls (numbered 1..8) and 8 boys (numbered 9..16). 
1,3,5,8 think boys are yucky
9,10,11,14 think girls are gross
these pairs are enemies:
[[1,2], [4,6], [4,7], [4, 9],[9,11], [12, 14], [14,16]]

The predicate to find two children are not enemies is defined as:

```
not_enemy(A, B) :-
    NotA #\= A #\/ NotB #\= B,
    tuples_in([[NotA, NotB]],
              [[1,2], [4,6], [4,7], [4, 9],[9,11], [12, 14], [14,16]]).
```

The above code was found [here](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/clpfd/clpfd.html)

but when I query ?- not_enemy(1,2) the output is true.

I have to use this long code instead:

```
not_enemy(A, B) :-
          A #=1 #==> B #\= 2,
          A #=4 #==> B #\= 6,
          A #=4 #==> B #\= 7,
          A #=4 #==> B #\= 9,
          A #=9 #==> B #\= 11,
          A #=12 #==> B #\= 14,
          A #=14 #==> B #\= 16.
```

Could anyone please help to correct the first piece of code? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The example is wrong, and mixing reifications with `tuples_in/2` is definitely *not* a good way to express the given constraints with CLP(FD). Your code is one correct way to do it (+1!). Another way is to apply the method @repeat describes: You can build the complement of the relation and use `tuples_in/2` to constrain the pairs to *compatible* elements. Yet another way is to negate the individual `tuples_in/2` constraints. Be careful though not to accidentally negate a `tuples_in/2` constraint that involves more than one pair, since that would not be logically equivalent to the other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found another answer, instead of using this

```
not_enemy(A, B) :-
    NotA #\= A #\/ NotB #\= B,
    tuples_in([[NotA, NotB]],
              [[1,2], [4,6], [4,7], [4, 9],[9,11], [12, 14], [14,16]]).
```

Just negate tuples_in with #\

```
not_enemy(A, B) :-
    #\ tuples_in([[A,B]],
                 [[1,2], [4,6], [4,7], [4, 9],[9,11], [12, 14], [14,16]]).
```

Comment: Does it works ? Great to know ! I thought \# was for reifiable constraints, and tuples_in doesn't fall in that category. So I didn't tried...

Comment: I checked the docs, and if after further investigation, your answer turns out to be correct, I will file a bug report on clpfd docs

Comment: Yes it did work. \# negates anything that follows(in clpfd).

Answer (score 6):

I would refine your code, just to make it generic

```
not_enemy(A, B) :-
    maplist(not_enemy(A,B), [[1,2], [4,6], [4,7], [4,9], [9,11], [12,14], [14,16]]).
not_enemy(A,B,[X,Y]) :-
    X #= A #==> Y #\= B.
```

I cannot find an appropriate way to use tuples_in to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Above use of `tuples_in/2` is wrong.

Think of `tuples_in` as a way of defining "compatibility tables":
Then it should be obvious that the combination with `(#\=)/2` cannot possibly work for expressing "incompatibility tables".

Why? Because---with an incompatibility table---we don't want to exclude *any single incompatible tuple*, but **all
of them** at the same time.

When working with finite domains, we can explicitly construct a compatibility table, by taking a Cartesian product as the basis from which the incompatible pairs are eliminated.

Comment: How? Compatibility table?

Comment: Thank you, I could grasp your idea conceptually, I shall try it in prolog.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment I have given above, I want to show you an important feature of the SWI-Prolog toplevel that helps to detect an obvious problem of the wrong formulation.

First, consider the obviously wrong answer of `not_enemy/2`:

```
?- not_enemy(1, 2).
true.
```

However, there is more to it, and you see that after you use:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_residue_vars, true).
true.
```

Then, the toplevel displays pending residual goals that are normally not shown because the involved variables do not appear in the query:

```
?- not_enemy(1, 2).
% with pending residual goals
_G454 in 0..1,
_G454#\/_G460#<==>1,
etc.
```

From this, it is already clear that something is wrong with the formulation: There are pending residual constraints, and CLP(FD) in general does not and cannot guarantee consistency of pending constraints. You have to use one of the enumeration predicates to see if there are any concrete solutions.

In this case, you get wrong results even if you use the enumeration predicates, because the problem is wrongly and awkwardly expressed. However, the pending residual constraints alone already give you a clear indication that you cannot treat the answers as concrete solutions.

The flag `toplevel_residue_vars` works by implicitly wrapping the query in an important predicate named `call_residue_vars/2`. This is available in SICStus and SWI to show *all* residual constraints. Use it to make sure that you are not accidentally creating unsatisfiable constraints somewhere in your formulation.

For such reasons, I strongly recommend you *avoid* side-effects, so that you can more declaratively reason about your code and use the toplevel to display answers and concrete solutions.